# C# failed to get response from HTTPS server

Tags: c#, httpclient

I have below c# code

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Then I got "Input string was not in a correct format." error when executing client.GetAsync(). But I confirmed the url is accessible (from web browser). Any idea about what the issue is? Appreciate any help.

Comment: what does the url contain - exactly, please paste into the question

Comment: Try : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 + SecurityProtocolType.Tls32;  Your certificate may be TLS 1.3.  Proxy may be enabled and you need to disable proxy in the client.  What OS are you using?  Usually these cases the browser is using different default HTTP headers and you need to modify the headers in the client.  HTTPS uses TLS for authentication which is done before HTTP Request is sent.  If TLS fails you never get a response because the request is never sent.  Error indicates you got a null response.

Comment: It can be thrown by `Convert.ToInt32` or `int.Parse`, look for them in your code.

Comment: Hi all, it is quite strange. I changed the url from the string to "new Uri("https://mypws.astrofans.net/api/cs/data/get?devicename=taiyuge&interval=realtime")" in GetAsync, then it works. I really have no idea about the behavior here.